# Re-use Array to Save Memory

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management

I'm working on a C# application that must graph extremely large amounts of data (data set sizes range between a million data points to 30 million data points).

Before graphing, I do linear interpolation to space the points evenly (interpolation is a part of the requirements of the software, so I can't avoid that).  This results in even more data points than the original set (e.g., 1 million points can easily become 1.5 million or more).

In a (foolish?) attempt to conserve memory, I've been interpolating and graphing in chunks.  For example, I set a chunk size of 100,000, so I interpolate the first 100,000 points and graph them, interpolate the second 100,000 points and graph them, so on and so on until all interpolated points have been graphed.

I use two arrays in parallel (representing the x and y values).  The arrays are reallocated before the start of the next chunk.  Unfortunately, for the largest data sets (around 30 million), the program throws an OutOfMemory error.

**I was wondering if it's possible to simply reuse the same two parallel arrays, overwriting old values with new values for each chunk?  Is this even a good idea?**

Read more on linear interpolation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Linear_interpolation

Comment: It depends on how you're using the data inside your *"and graph them"* process. If you just read the data once at that time then there shouldn't be any issues with re-using those same two arrays over-and-over.

Comment: 30M points * 2 coordinates * 8 bytes per double: 480MB.  Assuming you've a fairly new machine, this doesn't look vary scary; I don't think your coordinate arrays are the problem.